# Destroy a session

Tags: java, jsp, session

I Want to destroy a session in my project such that when I click on Logout, it goes to a page "KillSession.jsp" , in that file I've written "session.invalidate();" and then I redirect the user to the Login page.
But if I use the back button on my browser, it goes back to the page I have visited before even when I've logged out.
What to do?

Comment: please provide some more info, code, what framework are you working if any?

Comment: you could find your answer by doing some search on the net [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers?lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Your browser caches it, You need to add header to force your browser not to force it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don't cache the last page before you log out. You could do something like:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate");
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
```